# Poem for Calligraphy Art

Tags: poetry, calligraphy

It maybe very dumb, stupid and unwise that I have an interest in learning to write Chinese calligraphy when I can't write more than hundred Chinese words, but still I always think Chinese calligraphy is very beautiful kind of art that I want to get into and master someday. In my quest to this ambitious journey, What is an ideal Chinese poem that has good strokes (笔画) to practice my Chinese calligraphy?  (Also want it to have good and beautiful meaning, and so a love poem is preferred.) I only want to focus on 4x7=28 unique words instead of chasing the goose, since unlike English where there are only 26 geese (A-Z), Chinese have thousands if not millions of strange alien-like geese that Chinese people probably have not seem very frequently in their daily life.

Comment: [中國情詩](http://cls.hs.yzu.edu.tw/love/all/Poem_bestchoice.asp)

Comment: As a foreigner without success in calligraphy, I suggest you just choose what ever inspires you, but first spend a lot of time on the individual strokes. If your teacher is traditional you may spend months practicing dots (點）anyway，then months practicing single strokes. I have heard, many teachers like teaching pupils to write 永 because it contains many basic strokes. My Chinese brother likes making people write 教。

Comment: Given that you don't know that many characters, I would recommend to find some "easy" poems to start with. You can find those poems in the beginning chapters of any classical Chinese text book.

Answer (score 1):

There are four basic types of calligraphy: 
   1.Regular Script(楷书)
   2.Semi-cursive Scrip(行书)
   3.Clerical Script(隶书)
   4.Cursive Script(草书)

Normally I'll recommend start with Yan Zhenqing - Duobaota Bei. But I think Ouyang Xun - Thousand Character Text is better for you to try. It's covering lots of basic knowledge and widely used as a primer for teaching Chinese characters to children. Below is the link.

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AC%A7%E9%98%B3%E8%AF%A2#/media/File:%E6%AC%A7%E9%98%B3%E8%AF%A2%E8%A1%8C%E4%B9%A6%E3%80%8A%E5%8D%83%E5%AD%97%E6%96%87%E3%80%8B.jpg

So far I never see any Chinese calligraphy poem (ancient classic) is about love.

Answer (score 0):

A very famous poem good for practicing calligraphy is[《上邪》 (Shang Ye)](http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8A%E9%82%AA/1270334).

Answer (score 0):

Any of the *Three Hundred Tang Poems* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Hundred_Tang_Poems) are a nice place to start... This link seems to have their text viewable online (http://wengu.tartarie.com/wg/wengu.php?l=Tangshi).

Answer (score 0):

you can first learn some most popular poems and here are Poem for Calligraphy Art
http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/article/chinese-learning-tips/top-5-chinese-poems/